# WPF Binding Control's widths at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

WPF Binding Control Widths so they are always the same width

I would like to bind the width of a Window to the ActualWidth of a control on another window.

As I have acheived so far, it updates the width on only once on showing the window, but does not update as the source control changes width.

Window 1 with DockPanel control, which has the ActualWidth I wish to bind to (in practice there are multiple controls, but I've only put one DockPanel here for simplicity):

```
<Window x:Class="Testing1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WindowWithControl" Height="350" Width="525" Initialized="Window_Initialized" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closed="Window_Closed">

    <Grid Name="gridMain">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Name="dockBindSource" Grid.Row="0" >
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window 2 - This is the window I want to match the width of the control in the previous window.

```
<Window x:Class="Testing1.ProgressOverlay"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ProgressOverlay" Height="300" Width="300" ShowInTaskbar="False" Opacity="0.75" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Canvas Name="canvasPB" />
</Window>
```

Code in cs to test binding the width here. I need to do this at runtime, beacuse at design time I do not know which control the window will be linked to.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressOverlay po = new ProgressOverlay();
    po.Owner = this;
    Binding b1 = new Binding();
    b1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    b1.Source = this.dockBindSource.ActualWidth;
    po.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, b1);
    po.Show();
}
```

All I've read about implementing binding is the requirement of INotifyPropertyChanged. I've used this before on custom classes, but not sure how to use on an existing control class.
I presume I need to raise a property change event of some sort in this part of the XML: `<Canvas Name="canvasPB" />`
Otherwise I'll give up on binding and just add a SizeChanged event to the Canvas, but throught there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: Instead of `private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`, use `private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)`

Comment: @Nobody I'd prefer to link to control size change, but even so creating a new binding object at every size change event seems strange to me. With that approach, I'd tend to use this code instead: `po.Width = dockBindSource.ActualWidth;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems the binding on `Window.Width` is not working. Proposed workaround: set the window to `SizeToContent="Width"` and bind the width to the window content (`canvasPB`)

```
Binding b1 = new Binding("ActualWidth");
b1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
b1.Source = this.dockBindSource;
po.canvasPB.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, b1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Amazing simple solution. Good to know binding on `Window.Width` doesn't work!

Comment: Second part of solution is to put this into the window xaml, so that the window width resizes to the canvas width: `SizeToContent="Width"`

Comment: Yes I rushed into this first thing. Finally read the whole answer. Another important thing to do is to run `po.Show()` *before* `SetBinding()`, otherwise it will not appear correctly on initial load.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressOverlay po = new ProgressOverlay();
    po.Owner = this;
    Binding b1 = new Binding("ActualWidth");
    b1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    b1.Source = this.dockFilterClient;
    po.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, b1);
    po.Show();
}
```

The Binding's `Source` property holds a reference to the *source object* of the binding, while its `Path` references the (optionally nested) *source property*.

The Binding constructor with a string argument sets the `Path` property, equivalent to

```
b1.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth");
```

in your case.

Comment: No this doesn't work. Same outcome as the other code - the width does not get updated during resize.

Comment: The Binding must be TwoWay. However, that doesn't work with ActualWidth, because it's read-only. You should have a view model property instead.

Comment: @Clemens why TwoWay? the user expressed OneWay in the code. It should work with ActualWidth. BTW, if the actual behavior has to be a two-way binding, I agree that a VM is a solution.

Comment: No idea, it just doesn't work with a OneWay binding. Try it yourself, e.g. by binding to a Slider's Value in the main window.

Comment: @Clemens you're definitely right. It seems that the binding doesn't work across windows: there's plenty of questions like this one. I wonder how I never figured it out (that's the side-effect of working with VMs all the times).

Comment: That's why it's always a good idea to test code you post in answers.